# Excel formula Compare Data to previous 20 entries for change

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table for raw material offloads. All get tested, but some don't get offloaded right away.  I'm trying to create a formula that looks at the future 20 entries for the same railcar and see if it changed from "N" to "Y" for offload.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
CAR #       Offloaded?
CTCX733450      N
CTCX733450      Y
GATX207935      N
CTCX733472      Y
GATX207923      N
GATX207935      Y
GATX207923      Y
```

I've tried `COUNTIF` functions and `IF` functions. I can detect the duplicate railcars, but can't correspond the Y and N with the railcar.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a note for future questions:  it can help to include your existing code (i.e. using `COUNTIF` or `IF`), to help people see what methods you've already tried, and what result you are looking to get

Comment: I'm not positive what you are looking to do from this but you could use conditional formatting (change cell colors possibly) to easily see which ones are "N" and/or "Y"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` to check multiple columns at once.  For example

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:A22, A2, B3:B22, "Y")
```

This will take the value in cell A2 (CTCX733450), then look at the following 20 rows (Rows 3-22) to see how many time Column A is that value **and** Column B is "Y".  If it is greater than 0, then one of the next 20 instances of that Railcar has been Offloaded.

Notably, this "the next 20 rows", and not "the next 20 entries for the same railcar".  For *that*, we would need to use `AGGREGATE` and `INDEX` to find the 20<sup>th</sup> time that railcar next appears, which will be the final row we check.

For the time being, we will substitute for this row value with `ROW_VALUE`.  This then lets us rewrite our formula using `INDEX`, as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:INDEX(A:A, ROW_VALUE), A2, B3:INDEX(B:B, ROW_VALUE), "Y")
```

Simple enough!  The tricky bit, though, is now working out what value we should have for `ROW_VALUE`.  This is where the `AGGREGATE` comes in.

You see, we can use `AGGREGATE` to get the *k<sup>th</sup>* (fourth parameter) smallest (First parameter = `15`) non-error value (Second parameter = `6`) from a list of values (third parameter).  We can also make a list of Rows where column A is the same as the value in A2, by using `#DIV0!` (divide by zero) errors, and the fact that `TRUE`/`FALSE` can be treated as `1`/`0`

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A:A)/(A:A=A2), k)
```

In your case, we want *k* to be 20 + how many copies of railcar we already have.  We can count how many copies of the railcar have passed us by using `COUNTIF`, so long as we lock one end to the first row:

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A:A)/(A:A=A2), 20+COUNTIF(A$1:A2, A2))
```

Now, in *theory* we could shove that in as our `ROW_VALUE`.  In practice, I can immediately see 2 big problems with it.  The first, working on Whole Columns is **slow**.  Second, and more important:  What happens if there are *less* than 20 copies of the railcar remaining?  You get a `#NUM!` error, that's what.

We can fix both of these issues with `COUNTA` (assuming that there are no rows without railcar numbers).  For the first one, we will use `INDEX` again:

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A$1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A$1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20+COUNTIF(A$1:A2, A2))
```

Alternatively, you can rearrange this to get rid of the `COUNTIF` at the end, by starting your Range on the next row, and just looking for the 20<sup>th</sup> number:

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20)
```

For the second issue, we'll use `IFERROR`.  This is a simple function - it just says "Return this value, unless it is an error - then, use this other value instead".  Our "other value" will be the `COUNTA` of Column A, which *should* give us the last row in your list of Railcars:

```
IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20),COUNTA(A:A))
```

This then gives us our `ROW_VALUE`, which we can plug into our other earlier `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:INDEX(A:A, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20),COUNTA(A:A))), A2, B3:INDEX(B:B, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20),COUNTA(A:A))), "Y")
```

---

Finally, and optionally: we can make a slight boost in calculation time by working out if the `AGGREGATE` will error **before** it does so, by checking if there *are* at least 20 more entries for the Railcar.  This also replaces the `IFERROR` with an `IF` statement, but makes the whole equation longer:

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:INDEX(A:A, IF(COUNTIF(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)),A2)<20, COUNTA(A:A), AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20))), A2, B3:INDEX(B:B, IF(COUNTIF(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)),A2)<20, COUNTA(A:A), AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20))), "Y")
```

We have replaced this `ROW_VALUE`

```
IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20),COUNTA(A:A))
```

with this one instead

```
IF(COUNTIF(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)),A2)<20, COUNTA(A:A), AGGREGATE(15, 6, Row(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)))/(A3:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A))=A2), 20))
```